# The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."

Tags: ajax, iis, asp.net-web-api, web-config, cors

This is another CORS question. I have a weird issue.
I have an old application. i have access to inetpub but not the source code (only dlls and web.config).
So, before i make any POST call, there is a preflight call that is happening and somehow , the server is now allowing options to happen.

How do i make this work with just web.config or iis changes?

interestingly, Get call works. only post doesnt work.

I have added the following in Web.config of the api

```
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
```

in my test application, when i try to call the api, i am sending the following in the request headers

```
OPTIONS http://OldWebApiurl HTTP/1.1
Host: http://Oldwebapi.host
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://TestSite
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36
Access-Control-Request-Headers: accept, content-type
Accept: */*
Referer: http://testsite/page
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
```

Answer (score 1):

> How do i make this work with just web.config or iis changes?

I am afraid that this might not be possible with changes to those files only. For example if you are using ASP.NET Web API (which you seem to be using according to the tags used in your question) you might consult the [`following tutorial`](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api) explaining the required changes you need to make to your source code in order to enable CORS.

So long story short, get the code of this web application from source control, add the `config.EnableCors();` call to the bootstrapping section and decorate the controllers/actions that need to be accessible with CORS with the `[EnableCors(...)]` attribute. Then push back the changes you did in the source control, trigger a build and let the continuous delivery do the rest and deploy your changes to the target environment. Then you can enjoy CORS.

> interestingly, Get call works. only post doesnt work.

That's perfectly normal, most common browsers simply do not make a pre-flight request for GET AJAX calls because those are considered safe - those are not supposed to modify any server side state so they are allowed.

Comment: Thanks Darin, As i said, it is a old code.  The one developed by organization is not in the picture anymore. so no source control / continous build.  We just have the deployed dlls  in the inetpub. Since those apis are doing what they are supposed to be doing, it has been untouched for a long time.

Comment: Well, then I am afraid that you are pretty much f..ed up. If it is an old code that you don't even have access to the source of, then why are you even trying to do things like CORS and stuff? Let it die with its legacy, and start building on new blocks. Why are you even asking questions on how to enable CORS on Web API in this case when you know that the answer involves modifying the code as shown in the article I have linked to?

Comment: We are already doing that and ofcourse we are fed up :) . The problem is , we are releasing our new application in phases and we are not able to release the first version because none of the apis work.  Reworking all the apis are going to take some time.. i was definitely hoping that i could get this worked by web.config settings

Comment: Well, in this case all I can do (other than providing my answer here explaining how to enable CORS in Web API) is to wish you best of luck in your endeavor. Sorry to disappoint you, but you are definitely gonna need to update and recompile this Web API application if you want to even dream about CORS. AFAIK there's no an `<add key="EnableCORSInWebAPIBecauseWeAreReleasingOurNewApplicationInPhasesAndNoneOfTheApisWork" value="true" />` option available that you could use in web.config. Maybe in ASP.NET 7 there will be such an option. Until then you are left with code changes that need to be done.